# MapBox: Dynamic Markers with Vue

Tags: vue.js, mapbox

Can anyone advise which is the best way to call the `marker1` & `marker2` actions if the `departure` & `arrival` props are set? Is it to be done with async/await, if statement or for loop?

```
props: {
    departure: Object,
    arrival: Object
},
methods: {
    initMapBox() {
        const mapboxgl = require('mapbox-gl/dist/mapbox-gl.js');

        mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoiY3dHNkMDUifQ.xaSxrVMLZtfGAlWoGvB1PQ';
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: 'map',
            style: 'mapbox://styles/aasnapop/ck9d',
            center: [22.253, 45.419],
            zoom: 6
        });
        const marker1 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: '#FFFFFF', anchor: 'center' })
            .setLngLat([this.departure.longitude, this.departure.latitude])
            .addTo(map);

        const marker2 = new mapboxgl.Marker({ color: '#FFFFFF' })
            .setLngLat([this.arrival.longitude, this.arrival.latitude])
            .addTo(map);
    }
```

Comment: You can check if set in your mounted() method.

Answer (score 0):

A Vue watcher allows you to listen to the component data and run whenever a particular property changes.

I recommend reading this as this does exactly what you want:
https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html.

Mounted definitely is an option however, my assumption from the async/await comment by the author was that they wanted to keep track of the props changing and not only when it gets added to the DOM. If they are only to be used once, then mounted is definitely the way to go. @ehhc

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I added the watchers to check when the departure / arrival props change, however I struggle to figure out how to run the `new mapboxgl.Marker` method and add these markers to the map. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

@DragonInTraining I'm not sure whether `mounted` wouldn't be the appropriate place for it. In that hook, the component is already fully created. So the props are set and can be used. I don't think watchers would be good, because the props should not change later on..

I suggest using the `mounted`-hook therefore: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram

Comment: I am actually using the `mounted` hook to call the initMapBox() function, however I want that the markers are only to be called when the `departure`and `arrival` props are truthy and the .setLngLat() function shall take the coordinates from these two props. I update my code to reflect this now.